# If else jsx using <Link> in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render(){
    return(
        {startDate && endDate ? <Link to=`/event/${event_id}?start=${startDate}&?end=${endDate}` target="_blank"> : <Link to=`/event/${event_id}` target="_blank">
            <div>lots of my content here</div>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

This code might be easy to understand but it won't work, it has snytax error. I can use onClick because I want to open the link in a new tab. How to use if else  with `Link`? Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this,

```
render() {
  const linkTo = startDate && endDate
    ? `/event/${event_id}?start=${startDate}&?end=${endDate}`
    : `/event/${event_id}`;

  return (
    <Link to={linkTo} target="_blank">
      <div>lots of my content here</div>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few mistakes

1. `return` should return only one component
2. You have syntax error as parenthesis are not matching

See here

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
          {
           startDate && endDate
           ?
           <Link to=`/event/${event_id}?start=${startDate}&?end=${endDate}` target="_blank"/> 
           :
           <Link to=`/event/${event_id}` target="_blank"/>
          }
          <div>lots of my content here</div>
     </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: doing this how my content is clickable? u should wrap my content within the <Link>?

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){
   let link = `/event/${event_id}`;
   link = (startDate && endDate) ? `${link}?start=${startDate}&?end=${endDate}`;

    return(
        <Link to={link} target="_blank"> 
            <div>lots of my content here</div>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you Link to statement within `{}` and also you neeed to close the first `Link` tag too as well as end the ternary operator exression with `}`

```
render(){
    return(
        {startDate && endDate ? <Link to={`/event/${event_id}?start=${startDate}&?end=${endDate}`} target="_blank"><div>lots of my content here</div></Link> : <Link to={`/event/${event_id}`} target="_blank">
            <div>lots of my content here</div>
        </Link>
       }
    )
}
```

However if the Link tags have the same content. It makes more sense to have ternary expression on the link target only

```
render(){
        var link = (startDate && endDate) ? `/event/${event_id}?start=${startDate}&?end=${endDate}` : `/event/${event_id}`;

        return(
            <Link to={link} target="_blank">
                <div>lots of my content here</div>
            </Link>
           }
        )
    }
```

Comment: you miss understood my question, both link has the same content.

Comment: Then add the same content there, problem was that you were not closing the link tag in the first expression.

Comment: I have a limitation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971705/express-before-return-of-a-method-in-react

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem, because you can't use `if-else` for halves of react-components, but only for whole components or their internal parts.

It means that you **can't** use such code:

```js
{condition ? <Link to="1"> : <Link to="2">
  <div>lots of my content here</div>
</Link>}
```

and instead you could use such variant:

```js
const content = <div>lots of my content here</div>
{condition ? <Link to="1">{content}</Link> : <Link to="2">{content}</Link/>}
```

or you can use condition for `to` parameter, as was proposed in other answers