# Expression before return of a method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a method in my render method

```
render(){
    const { x } = this.state; 
    return(
        {this.someMethod(x)}
    )
}

someMethod(x){
   return(
      <div>some content</div>
   )
}
```

Can I still do expression in someMethod? This will not work

```
someMethod(x){
       x === 1 ? 2 : 3; <-- this will not work
       return(
          <div>some content</div>
       )
    }
```

I know I can do expression within jsx but I don't want to. How to do expression before the return?

Comment: Why doesn't `x === 1 ? 2 : 3` work? You've not included an error message, nor a complete example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @fubar that's just a sample expression.

Comment: Fine, but you're still not providing _any_ information as to what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call within a div and assign the expression value to another variable

```js
class App extends React.Component {
   state = { x: 1}
   
   someMethod(x){
   console.log('here');
    var g = (x === 1) ? 2: 3
     return(
        <div>some content {g}</div>
     )
  }
   render(){
    const { x } = this.state; 
    return(
        <div>{this.someMethod(x)}</div>
    )
  }

  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: wow just wrap with a `<div>` will do? i don't understand react at all.

Comment: The thing is that when you call a function to return an element, you may have returned multiple elements, so you must wrap them within a div.